# mknod of content in directory

Tags: mount, storage, cloud

I would like to create a virtual device from a directory i.e. you know, there's these cloud storage providers like dropbox and co and they generally have a software client and then give you access to files saved with them in a certain directory in your home directory. Now I would like to, instead being able to access the files in a directory, I would like to be able to mount it anywhere and access the files like as if they were on a device. How can I create a virtual device like this using mknod

**edit 1**: I would like to mount multiple of these devices together in one directory using mhddfs (http://romanrm.ru/en/mhddfs) if possible

**edit 2**: I am trying it out with Ubuntu One and Dropbox and I have created `~/virtcld` in my home and "mounted" both cloud directories like this: `mhddfs ~/Dropbox/ ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/virtcld/ -o allow_other` then I have created a bunch of test files in my virtualcd like `time dd if=/dev/zero of=test13.bin bs=1024 count=1000000` but once my Dropbbox is filled up, the files do not start to upload to the ubuntu One directory instead...

Comment: Can you try expanding your question? I don't understand what you're trying to do? I'm with you on the Dropbox cloud part, not getting the reason you want to use mknod for anything? The directories that Dropbox exposes to you; you can export that directory using something like Samba or NFS to other systems if that's your angle.

Comment: @slm, please see edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) [plugin](https://github.com/arekzb/dropfuse) for Dropbox and many other services. I don't see how mknod relates.

Comment: please see edit above

Answer (score 2):

Given you're trying to make use of [mhddfs](http://romanrm.ru/en/mhddfs) to create a virtual directory of other directories it seems like you should be able to just provide the paths to Dropbox folders as arguments to it.

This is an example from the URL above:

```
$ mhddfs /mnt/hdd1,/mnt/hdd2,/mnt/hdd3 /mnt/virtual -o allow_other
```

These directories are the mounted devices, not the actual HDD's (`/dev/sda1`, etc.). So I would think something like this would do:

```
$ mhddfs /path/to/Dropbox1 /path/to/Dropbox2 /mnt/virtDropbox -o allow_other
```

#### UPDATE #1

In doing additional research I do not think you'll be able to use Dropbox with mhddfs. Dropbox apparently needs the filesystem to support the ability to provide hardlinks which mhddfs seems not to.

*excerpt [Using Dropbox With Your Seedbox To Download Torrents](http://torrentfreaknews.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-dropbox-with-your-seedbox-to.html)*

> [Why you need this step: If you try to install Dropbox the prescribed
>   way (http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall) it
>   will fail. This is because your home directory on BigSB is mounted
>   with mhddfs. mhddfs doesn't support hard links, which Dropbox needs.]

*The same thing is echoed here in the [Dropbox Forums - Problems installing on Linux](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=27211)*

> However, I was able to get this working after realizing that my server
>   provider had mounted /home with mhddfs file system (which does not
>   support hard links) After accessing the underlying drive I was able to
>   extract the tarball and run dropbox just fine

Comment: please see edit 2 above... any more suggestions?